# what is facebook application key and how can get this?

Tags: facebook, facebook-sdk-3.1

In all articles about Using facebook SDK that I have read we need **application key** or

**Application Api**. For example:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/98745/Using-Facebook-SDK-3-01-with-C-NET

I have created an app in facebook and I have **AppID** and **App secret**

but there is no application key. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **AppID** is the application key, they just called it that way.